# Prevent Termux from opening STL files

Tags: default-applications, termux

I have [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page) installed and when I try to open `STL` (3D model) it opens a Termux instead my STL viewer. How to prevent this behavior? There is no setting for Termux "open by default".

[image]

Comment: Based on experiences, you need to "Reset the app preferences" from Settings - Apps - See all apps - 3-dot menu instead. Note that this will reset *all* app preferences. The "Open by default" is only for web links, not internal file associations. However, just to make sure that your other apps also register STL files on their AndroidManifest (this needs to be implemented by the devs). Otherwise, while you can open the files directly from those apps, they still won't appear as a selection when you're trying to open the STL files from outside the apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot reproduce your approach. There is only menu item "Show System" under three dots in Apps - See all apps. AOS 11 (Asus stock ROM)